# Gerrit REST API and web GUI with different results

Tags: rest, gerrit

It seems that the web interface of Gerrit and the REST API show different results for the review votes.

For example, [Change I78c787fd5dd09fc7700f3093341532fe23f20eb8](https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/I78c787fd5dd09fc7700f3093341532fe23f20eb8) from the Android Gerrit review instance shows that Dima Zavin voted `+2 (LGTM, approved)`.

The default values for the Android instance are

```
-2: Do not submit
-1: I would prefer that you didn't submit this 
 0: No score
+1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve
+2: Looks good to me, approved
```

However, the REST API returns no `+2` at all, only `+1`:

```
curl "https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=change:I78c787fd5dd09fc7700f3093341532fe23f20eb8&o=DETAILED_LABELS"
```

Interestingly, this URL seems to work:

```
curl "https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/I78c787fd5dd09fc7700f3093341532fe23f20eb8/detail"
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a [bug in the Gerrit](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=9385&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Stars%20Milestone%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary) backend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotation marks to your curl URL:

```
curl "https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=change:I78c787fd5dd09fc7700f3093341532fe23f20eb8&o=DETAILED_LABELS"
```

Comment: Thanks for the remark, fixed it. However, this does not solve the problem itself.